# Update TextView When Date is Changed in the DatePicker

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-datepicker

I have Added A date picker View in my .xml layout

```
<DatePicker
      android:id="@+id/datePicker"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="150dp"
      android:calendarViewShown="false"
      android:datePickerMode="spinner"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/age"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
```

and a text view which should show the age of the user

```
 val year = binding.datePicker.year.toString().toInt()
 val cd = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR).toString().toInt()
 val agu = cd - year binding.age.text = "$agu\nYears"
```

When the app is launched, the age does not update when I change the values in the date picker.
How to update the textview whenever I change the year in date picker?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple implementation of datePicker
When ever you update your date its show you a toast message with new date

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val datePicker = findViewById<DatePicker>(R.id.datePicker)
        val today = Calendar.getInstance()
        datePicker.init(today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        ) { _, year, month, day ->
            val msg = "You Selected: $day/$month/$year"
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

}
```

And this is xml codes

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: I don't want to show toast, I want to get that value updated live in the text view. How can I do that?